# bootrap down button does not work even though I included all files in it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap drop down button does not work properly even I included all libraries javascript and popper files which I downloaded through npm.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>three grid </title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<br><br><br>
 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js type=text/javascript"></script>
<script src="popper/popper.min.js type=text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js type=text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: my question is simple dear,when i open my code in browser it gives me only button not drop down menu.

Comment: Did you check if your JS files were loaded properly? Did you tried to load an element with jQuery from the Browser console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your Js or jQuery file it will fix your problem.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>three grid </title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <br><br><br>
     <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Dropdown button
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`it` [works here](https://jsfiddle.net/adarshsingh87/qafjvt2p/1/) my guess is there might be some error in the linking of the downloaded files try linking bootstrap through CDN and try again.